# Windows converted my folders conataining .jpg files into Binary (application/octet-stream) type

Tags: binary

im kind of beginner in linux though i have been using them since 2011. Anyway my problem is that while i connected my ssd in a windows desktop, i was asked if i could let windows fix some problems into it and i press the ok, unfortunately and all my fοlders and files were converted into Binary (application/octet-stream) type that i cannot open of course and the contents of the folders are lost.

[image]

A friend of mine achieved to restore the .pdf, .xls and .doc files but not the .jpg. Is it possible the folders that contained .jpg to be restored? I'm a bit desperate.

My SSD was parted into 4 sections:(as it shows now) Windows, System, 40GB Volume(ext3/ext4), 239GB Volume (filesystem type: msdos)

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, 64-bit, Gnome Version 42,9. This happened while i used the desktop in my office at work. i connected my ssd

Comment: can you add in the questions examples of some of these jpegs what `file` shows for those files? Oh and this seems similar to this q:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230879/how-to-repair-corrupted-jpeg-files-that-still-have-their-thumbnails

Comment: i don't think this case is similar, anyway i've posted the screenshot of how this files are.

Comment: The problem is that all the folders that  contained jpg files are converted into binary archives, i can't see the containing jpgs. I have edited my initial post and i posted also some screenshots.

Comment: Can you tell us which partition had these folder with JPEG files? Is it the 40 GB NTFS `/dev/sdc2` partition you have highlighted in your screenshot, **or** 239 GB FAT `/dev/sdc5`, **or** 40 GB ext4 `/dev/sdc6`? Which partition did Windows "fix"?

Comment: No, this isn't, this was randomly highlighted. All my folders and files were in the Filesystem Partition 5, 239GB FAT that was my shared storage partition for linux and windows.